# trouble with sublime text and /var/www/html

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, lamp, sublime-text

I installed ubuntu 14.04 with mysql and the rest of lamp.
I created a file called test.php in sublime and when i try to save this file it says unable to safe file in var/www/html

I tried to chown user:user /var/www

but it didnt do anything

I know there are many similir threads to this 1 but id like you to answer it for me so i can understand what i need to do which is not the case with other posts/comments

I had lamp istalled before and i had no problems creating files andsaving them

Answer (score 1):

`sudo chmod 775 /var/www` should do it, it is a simple permission problem.

Comment: it doesnt do anything, still the same problemcant save in /var/www

Answer (score -2):

Try: `sudo chown -R user:user /var/www`

Comment: Very Bad Idea™ !